# Триггер MySQL с выборкой значения для переменной из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql

Задача. Триггер срабатывает после обновления таблицы, если изменен статус заказа. Сначала проверяем настройки пользователя, который делал заказ. Если уведомления включены (поле notify) и пользователь подписан на обновления статуса заказа (поле notify_status), то вставляем в таблицу с уведомлениями новое сообщение. Слепил из того, что было в Гугле:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE notify_status INT;
SET notify_status = (SELECT notify_status FROM user WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND notify = '1');
IF notify_status > 0 THEN
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO notifications (notify_dateDelivered, notify_title, notify_body, notify_userID) VALUES (NOW(), 'Статус Вашей заявки изменен', CONCAT('Статус Вашей заявки: ', NEW.order_status), NEW.user_id);
  END; 
  END IF;
END
```

Не срабатывает.

Comment: что значит 'не срабатывает' ? тихо ничего 'не срабатывать' не может, должны быть какие нибудь сообщения об ошибке. Вообще получать значение из таблицы в переменную принято `select notify_status into notify_status from user ...`. Только это все совершенно не нужно, проще написать `insert into notifications ... select NOW(), 'Статус Вашей заявки изменен', ... from user WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id AND notify = '1' and notify_status > 0`

Comment: Не срабатывает потому, что ничего не происходит после обновления записей в таблице. Куда должны выводиться ошибки работы триггера?

Comment: если есть ошибки выполнения - то прямо в момент обновления записей. убедитесь, что триггер успешно создался, могли быть ошибки при создании, которые например не показало средство через которое вы создавали триггер

Comment: select notify_status into notify_status - кажется, это сработало